# exception when trying to print an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have this very little program in Java (just started to learn this language):

```
package hellojava;

public class Hellojava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int[] revs = reverse(nums);
        for (int i : revs) {
            System.out.println(revs[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] reverse(int[] list) {
        int[] result = new int[list.length];
        for (int i=0, j=result.length-1; i<list.length; i++, j--) {
            result[j] = list[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It throws this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 at hellojava.Hellojava.main(Hellojava.java:9).
```

So I pretty know what's wrong and know how to fix it, but my question is about that for loop. I thought that this enhanced for loop will work here, but it doesn't. Why's that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the enhanced for loop gives the values of the array, not the indexes.  So, `10` the value is returned, which is an invalid index.

Your loop beginning:

```
for (int i : revs) {
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int index = 0; index < revs.length; index++)
{
    int i = revs[index];
}
```

Comment: Damn, it's so easy! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

The enhanced for loop gives you the values in an array, not the indexes. Try

```
for (int i : revs) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
    for (int i : revs) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

You are using a `foreach` statement instead of a `for` indexed loop. The `foreach` loop iterates the array for you and assign the element of the array to `i` so don't consider it as an index of an array.

Here is an Oracle documentation on the [For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
System.out.println(revs[i]);
```

with

```
System.out.println(i);
```

Explanation: The variable `i` is the integer element and not an index.